# How to get session values from asp.net to angularjs

Tags: c#, sql, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm using (asp.net and angular js) as client and web api as a server
and i want to pass the session value(like user name ,password and other value) from code behind in asp.net to anngular js
is there any one can help me for that
as in master page

```
   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Restaurant>().Result;
            Session["RestInfo"] = data;
            Response.Redirect("SearchResult.aspx");
        }
```

and i want

```
  Session["RestInfo"] = data;
```

to redirect to the page SearchResult.aspx which its code is angularjs
How i get and implement that session value to angularjs

Comment: There are plenty of AngularJS tutorials all over the internet.. why don't you show us what you have tried on your own vs waiting on someone to just give you the quick answer.. part of learning is doing.. so do some research / work on your own first.

Comment: actually i want the value to angularjs function  from session in asp.net
i tried to put it in lable then take it but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Give the Label an ID and check from JS using this ID: <%= lblIDHere.ClientID %>

Answer (score -1):

That's a very broad question, but I can try to answer it generically.

What you want to be doing is binding the `<asp:Label>` element using the `ng-model` angular attribute. You can accomplish this by declaring your label with the following attribute markup.

`ng-model="variableToBindTo"`

Then, in your controller, declare `$scope.variableToBindTo` with the data you want to display in the label.

Comment: actually i want the value to angularjs function  from session in asp.net
i tried to put it in lable then take it but it doesn't work

Comment: ASP.NET and angular weren't really designed to mix here. I think your best bet might be jQuery, if you want to extract information straight from the DOM.